# Recycler view expand scrollable section?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a list of elements that is scrollable across the bottom of the screen:

| [x] [y] [z] |

If I have > 3 items, i.e. v, w, x, y, z, and I scroll to the left, then v, w, and x are displayed, and y and z are off the screen to the right.

My goals is that I would like to be able to scroll to the left until v is all the way on the right:

| [x] [y] [z] |

Scroll finger left to right, it should end up like so:

|  -------    [v] |

(Had to add dashes for stack overflow's formatting).

I've tried enabling over scroll, but this doesn't do anything. Any thoughts?

Comment: A simple approach would be to add empty items before the [v] that just fill up the same space as the other items. In this case you'd need to add 2 empty items to have that behavior.

Comment: @J.Hegg this works but if I add elements to the list it will cause a full refresh, making the list look choppy. I’m using a list adapter to prevent choppiness.

Comment: You will need to adapt your diff util or otherwise append the empty items to the list as soon as you get your first items